# Are there security vulnerabilities, including view in another view

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

I wrote this code as general_view.php:

```php
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Header section omitted -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <?php include $view; ?>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have two questions about this code.

1. Does this code occur security vulnerabilities, for example, directory traversal?
2. If the previous question is true, I want to know the right way to include view in another view.

Thank you!

Comment: You are using codeigniter or laravel?

Comment: no there isn't and why are you using `include` with CI?

Comment: better include your header and footer to view, not main body. then you can reuse them in other views too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it has nothing to do with security here it is just a design pattern and actually it is somehow recommended to keep your code clean and most importantly `DRY` (**Don't Repeat Yourself**) .. and you can create a master template as you tried to do here like this: `view/templates/master_view.php`

```
$this->load->view('layouts/header');
echo $body; // we will make init it in controller
$this->load->view('layouts/footer');
```

Now that we have a template lets create its parts `header` & `footer` like this: `views/layouts/header.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Header Assets -->
    </head>
    <body>
```

`views/layouts/footer.php`

```
        <!-- Footer Assets -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your controller you can now use that master template like this:

```
$data = array();
$data['body'] = $this->load->view('your_view_for_current_method', '', TRUE); // TRUE here to generate it as a string
// Now load the template
$this->load->view('templates/master_view', $data);
```

You can move it to your MY_Controller and create a `render_view`method if you want and just pass the view to it.

Comment: Hmm... I understood I can't consist up the default template as one file, right? or does this framework have a function to include other view in view like `$this->fetch()` of CakePHP?

Comment: You can use `$this->load->view();` anywhere in your application even inside any view and as i described earlier you can output it directly or store it on a variable and send it to the view and just echo it .. i hope you got it! .. codeigniter is extremely flixable

Comment: OK, I've got it. I understood `$this` in a view means the controller which calls the view. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No By default you can not accesses the views directly in Code Igniter Therefore "$view" by which you mean any views you want to include in your general_view.php may not be accessed directly that is in case of directory traversal. Its completely secure if you haven't made a controller for "$view" and simply include it in general_view.php